# Fetch image from Directory and show on JFrame Form

Tags: java, directory, jframe

I have made a code which search file(image, text) from directory and its Working Too , Now I want to show Search File (image) on J Frame's Component like J Panel or something else , here is my code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        findFile(jTextField2.getText(),new File(jTextField1.getText()));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    } 
 

public void findFile(String name,File file1)throws IOException
    {      
        File[] list = file1.listFiles();       
        if(list!=null)  
     {                          
        for(File file2 : list)
        {            
            if (file2.isDirectory())
            {
                findFile(name,file2);             
            }
            else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(file2.getName()))
            {                                                              
                
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File found at : "+name);
                                             
            }                      
        }        
      }
    }
```

I got Two Textfields which Take image(abc.png) name and directory Folder(E:) and tell where it is located , now I want to Show it on J  Frame as well , I don't know how to do this

Comment: So, basically, your `findFile` can "find" the file you want.  This should probably return a `File` reference to the "found" file (or `null` if it can't find one), then, you should probably load the file using [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and then you could just a [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) to show it.  You should also probably look at [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you help me through code , I am beginner

Comment: Start with the links I've provide, don't try to solve the whole problem in one step, figure each part in isolation and then start putting it together.  What you're asking has been before, so there a plenty of existing examples